# Creating a batch file that runs a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, batch-file

I want to create a batch file which can run a Ruby file like `test.rb`.

Anyone have any idea how to create one?

Im using Ruby 2.0.0 and Windows 10.

Comment: [you can check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094778/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-ruby-code-into-batch-file) though the only thing you need is to use `ruby c:\test.rb`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems premature. We'd like to see your effort toward solving this, and, if it didn't work we'll help you get it working. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this.

```
cd location
test.rb
```

This might also work.

```
cd ruby_install_location
ruby.exe c:/fullpath/test.rb
```